# Where should I run tests at build or release pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, pipeline, build-pipeline

I'm trying to set up a build and release pipeline, but I saw that it is possible to run visual studio tests in a build pipeline as well as in a release pipeline. Does anybody have a advice which one I should choose?

Comment: depends on what test. unit\intergation on build. smoke\ui on release

Comment: @4c74356b41 but is it also possible to run the unit tests at the release ?

Comment: well, no. because you'd need the code to run those, not binaries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Where should I run tests at build or release pipeline?

Indeed, just like the comment of 4c74356b41, it depends on what you test. In general, `unit`\ `intergation` on build. `smoke` \ `UI` on release.

> but is it also possible to run the unit tests at the release ?

The answer is yes.

According to the official document [Visual Studio Test task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops):

> Use this task **in a build or release pipeline to run unit and
>   functional tests** (Selenium, Appium, Coded UI test, and more) using the
>   Visual Studio Test Runner.

But, when you run the unit tests at the release pipeline, you need to use copy task and Publish build artifacts task to copy the `dll` and `test.dll` to the artifacts, so that we could get it in the release pipeline.

[image]

Then we could test it in the release pipeline.

Check [the similar thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/349742/vstest-in-release-pipeline-cant-find-tests-no-test.html) for some more details.

As test, it works fine on my side:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think it is better to run UI tests on build pipeline, you do not have to wait when you want to deploy.